# Insert vertical bar in list element

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to insert vertical bar inside an element list. 
The vertical bar must be change color in according to the type of element,
is that possible?

I show this in the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The easiest way to do it would be to simple add a `View` with a background color in your row layout.

Something like this would achieve the desired behavior:

**XML layout**

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/color_bar"
   android:layout_width="16dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**In Kotlin** (perhaps a `RecyclerView` adapter):

```
val colorBar = findViewById(R.id.color_bar)
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color_here)
colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a cardview and edit its background in the drawable folder